# css float 4 divs in a square order (float-left only 2° and 4° does not work)

Tags: css, css-float

I have 4 divs

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
<div id="third"></div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

and I need to align them in a "square" order:
[image: divs order]

I've tried to float-left only 2°div and 4°div, but it does not work.

Unfortunately **I can't use**
a container with a defined width and all divs left-floated

```
<div id="container" style="width: 250px">
  <div id="first"  style="float: left"></div>
  <div id="second" style="float: left"></div>
  <div id="third"  style="float: left"></div>
  <div id="fourth" style="float: left"></div>
</div>
```

or position absolute/relative left, top etc. in my actual project...

So I hope that there is some float trick to solve my problem..

Answer (score 16):

```
<style>
    .divSquare{
        width:48%; height:200px; margin:4px; border:1px solid black; float: left
    }
</style>    

<div class="divSquare">1</div>
<div class="divSquare">2</div>
<div style='clear:both'></div>
<div class="divSquare">3</div>
<div class="divSquare">4</div>
```

I assume you can define the Height explicitly, and you **CAN** set a percentage Width.
The `divSquare`'s Width is set to 48% (less than 50%) because the 4px margin and 1px border occupy room either.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTp9f/1/) to see this in action.

Comment: `"Unfortunately I can't use
a container with a defined width and all divs left-floated"` ... interesting answer

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using clear? Check this example:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>

div { height: 100px; float: left; width: 100px; }
#a { background: blue; }
#b { background: red; }
#c { background: green; clear: left; }
#d { background: black; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T5X9A/

Answer (score 3):

I'm faking a square with the `height: 0;` & `padding-bottom: 50%` - but besides that - the floating part should be clear. Here is [a jsFiddle too](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Y4cPC/). I also didn't prefix the box-sizing... - you can google it. Good luck!

### HTML

```
<div class="block one">1</div>
<div class="block two">2</div>
<div class="block three">3</div>
<div class="block four">4</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

.block {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.one {
    background: yellow;
}

.two {
    background: lightblue;
}

.three {
    background: orange;
}

.four {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does a simple clear float work? This HTML appears to do what you want:

```
<html>
<style>
    div {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
        margin: 8px;
    }
    #third {
        clear: left;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="first">1</div>
<div id="second">2</div>
<div id="third">3</div>
<div id="fourth">4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really is based on the width of the four divs. The container has a width of 250px so if the first two divs are 125px in width then they'll fill up the first row pushing all the remain divs down. If the divs were all width: 50% that'll have the same effect. If the div's widths were anything less than 33.3333% then the at least three divs will pile up in the first row. Float left allows the boxes to go side by side until it hits the parent's width limit. What you can do is control the width by:

```
#container > div {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Or you can clear the floats every third div.

```
#container > div:nth-of-type(3n + 3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ssKK/1/